# How to get all product attribute of a attribute group of Default attribute set?

Tags: magento2, module, attributes

I want to get the collection of all product attributes of an attribute group in the Default attribute set in Magento 2.

Is there any filter available like `group_id` or group name or something else ?

Comment: Are you looking for list of attribute of Attribute set?

Comment: List of attribute in a attribute group. Not based on attribute set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add this to your class:

```
protected $attributeRepository;
protected $searchCriteriaBuilder;
protected $sortOrderBuilder;

public function __construct(
    ....
    \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductAttributeRepositoryInterface $attributeRepository,
    \Magento\Framework\Api\SortOrderBuilder $sortOrderBuilder,
   ....
)
{
    ....
    $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
    $this->attributeRepository = $attributeRepository;
    $this->sortOrderBuilder = $sortOrderBuilder;
    ....
}
```

Now you added the dependencies. You need a method to retrieve the attributes based on the attribute group id.

```
public function getAttributes($groupId)
{
    $sortOrder = $this->sortOrderBuilder
            ->setField('sort_order')
            ->setAscendingDirection()
            ->create();
    $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder
            ->addFilter(\Magento\Eav\Api\Data\AttributeGroupInterface::GROUP_ID, $groupId)
            ->addFilter(\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductAttributeInterface::IS_VISIBLE, 1) //if you want only visible attributes
            ->addSortOrder($sortOrder)
            ->create();
    $groupAttributes = $this->attributeRepository->getList($searchCriteria)->getItems();
    return $groupAttributes;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marius , It's really helpful and its works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code for filtering by **group id:**

```
$groupId = 1;   
$this>_objectManager>create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Attribute\Collection')->setAttributeGroupFilter($groupId);
```

Comment: I tried this but its not working

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the easiest way :

```
use Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeManagementInterface;

    public function __construct(
        AttributeManagementInterface $attributeManagement,
.....
 )
    {       
 $this->_attributeManagement = $attributeManagement;
.....
}

    /**
     * @return \Magento\Eav\Api\Data\AttributeInterface[]
     */
    public function getAttributesetAttributes($attributesetid){
        $attributes = $this->_attributeManagement->getAttributes(ProductAttributeInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CODE,$attributesetid);
        return $attributes;
    }
```